# how to create custom kendo.ui.Window for edit in kendo.ui.grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm starter in kendo.Ui , i write this code for create grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BrandViewModel>(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.BrandName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.BrandAbbr);
        columns.Bound(p => p.SrcImage);

        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Edit").Click("editItem"));

    })

    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("CustomCommand_Read", "Brand"))
         .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))

               )
)
```

i want when user click in `Edit` button open `Edit view` in kendo window i write this code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("Details")
    .Title("Customer Details")
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true)
    .Draggable(true)

    .Width(300)
)



<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div id="details-container"> <!-- this will be the content of the popup -->
        BrandName: <input type='text' value='#= BrandName #' />

    </div>
</script>
```

and java script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());

    function editItem(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

        $("#Details").data("kendoWindow").refresh({
            url: "/Brand/Edit/" + dataItem.Id
        });
        $("#Details").data("kendoWindow").open();



    }
</script>
```

this code work fine For the first time I click on a button,But when I click a second time.I encountered the following error

```
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'refresh' of undefined or null reference
```

please help me, thanks all

Comment: Learned something new from your question that had nothing to do with your question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember I had a similar issue with this control. Now it works for me with the following Javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());
    var windowObject;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        windowObject = $("#Details").data("kendoWindow");
    });

    function editItem(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

        windowObject.refresh({
            url: "/Brand/Edit/" + dataItem.Id
        });
        windowObject.open();
    }
</script>
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: @Joffrey Kern - This helped me as well in a problem I had binding a kendow Window to a template. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, by default, the window will be destroyed (removed from the DOM) on closure. I would suggest removing the "undefined" condition i added in the example below and, instead, dont create the "Details" div in the first place.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());

    function editItem(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

        if($("#Details") == undefined)
            $("body").append("<div id=\"Details\"></div>

        $("#Details").data("kendoWindow").refresh({
            url: "/Brand/Edit/" + dataItem.Id
        });
        $("#Details").data("kendoWindow").open();



    }
</script>
```